# Kafka Streams not triggering output for joined streams?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, confluent-platform

I have raw streams from 3 mysql tables, 1 primary and two child table. I tried to join three raw streams and transformed into single output stream. It works if there is any update on parent stream but not triggering output if anything changes on child stream.

```
    @StreamListener
    public Stream<Long, Output> handleStreams(@Input KStream<Long, Parent> parentStream,
    @Input KStream<Long, Child1> child1Stream,
    @Input KStream<Long, Child2> child2Stream) {

    KTable<Long, Parent> parentTable = convertParent(parentStream);
    KTable<Long, ArrayList<Child1>> child1Table = convertChild1(parentStream);
    KTable<Long, ArrayList<Child2>> child2Table = convertChild2(parentStream);

    parentTable
           .leftJoin(child1Table, (parent, child1List) -> new Output(k, v))
           .leftJoin(child2Table, (output, child2List) -> output.setChild2List(child2List))
           .toStream()
        }
```

Any new add or update on parent stream is picked up the processor and joins it with other KTable and return it on output stream. But any add or update on child1stream or child2stream doesn't trigger an output stream.

I thought making all input streams as KTable, they will always store changes as all of them have same key and any update on parent or child tables will be picked up the joins. But it is not happening, can anyone suggest what I am missing in this ?

I already tried KStream-KStream, Stream-KTable, KTable-KTable joins, none of them worked in case of child updates.

-Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you show where you have the `EnableBinding` and the processor interface that you are binding to?

This doesn't look right to me:

```
@StreamListener
    public Stream<Long, Output> handleStreams(@Input KStream<Long, Parent> parentStream,
    @Input KStream<Long, Child1> child1Stream,
    @Input KStream<Long, Child2> child2Stream) {
```

You are not specifying a binding on the inputs. You need to have something like this when you have multiple inputs:

```
@StreamListener
        public Stream<Long, Output> handleStreams(@Input("input1") KStream<Long, Parent> parentStream,
        @Input("input2") KStream<Long, Child1> child1Stream,
        @Input("input3") KStream<Long, Child2> child2Stream) {
```

Each of those inputs needs to be defined in the processor interface. See here for an example: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-table-join/src/main/java/kafka/streams/table/join/KafkaStreamsTableJoin.java#L46

Comment: Sorry, this is just a pseudo representation of the problem. I have the code same way, followed same example. It works. My question is more on a concept. Any update or insert on primary stream works but if any change on just child stream doesn't trigger an output object.

Comment: How do you receive raw streams from mysql? The child streams get their data from kafka topics. Are you sure that the messages are arriving to those kafka topics from mysql?

Comment: yes, I am using debezium with kafka connect. I see new messages in partitioned aggregate store topics for child stream but they do not appear on output.

Comment: Still a bit unclear. what do you mean by "output" in the previous comment? Are you seeing the messages streamed to "child1Stream" and "child2stream"?

Comment: yes, message are streamed to child1stream and child2stream and also getting streamed to aggregate stores. Since messages are in aggregate stores (as they are KTable), I expect it to perform joins as shown in the code above and should generate a stream of output object (which is composite of primary, child1 and child2 objects).

Comment: Ok. since you are getting the messages, I think spring-cloud-stream is out of the way at that point. It orchestrates everything and steps out of the critical path. Maybe someone from kafka-streams can chime in? If you can share a project where we can reproduce the issue, I may be able to look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Notice how your child tables are created from the same stream as the parentTable:

```
KTable<Long, ArrayList<Child1>> child1Table = convertChild1(parentStream);
KTable<Long, ArrayList<Child2>> child2Table = convertChild2(parentStream);
```

Not sure what convertChild1 and convertChild2 methods do, but shouldn't they be given child1Stream and  child2Stream as argument, respectively?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. That was a typo in writing the question. Also convert method just do group by key and aggregate. Child stream can have multiple record for the foreign key.